# lookup recordset value in another recordset

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba, recordset

what method should I be using when I want to search/lookup a recordset value in another recordset?
For example I want it to run a set of results for this year, I then want to for each record search another recordset (previous year) and see if they exist. If they do I then want to pull that data out.
E.g. In one recordset there is a ist of Premier league teams and their finishing positions for 2012. In another recordset we have the same but with 2013 positions.
I want to be able to loop through the 1st recordset and for each record in recordset 1 lookup the 2012 position in recordset 2 and print these using Debug.Print.
I hope I'm clear.
What is the best method for going about this? Using arrays or recordsets? Or another method?

recordset1
Team    2013_position
Manchester United   1
Manchester City 2

recordset2
Team    2012_Position
Manchester United   2
Manchester City 1

Comment: When you say recordset, what do you mean? Are you talking about records in a table or something like a VBA DAO/ADO recordset?

Comment: Yes I mean a VBA recordset. eg Set rst = db.OpenRecordset()

Comment: Do you have access to them not in recordset form? You can write a SQL query much easier than cursoring around a recordset for everything.

Comment: I do have access to them outside a recordset but I need to do it in VBA using recordset or array or any other possible/sensible way.

Comment: Is it possible to show examples of the data? I want to make sure I understand it before I advocate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use a query with 1 parameter (the teamname)
ala: qry = "select score from table2 where teamname = ?"

```
rs1 = recordset1
do until .eof
  qry1.parameter(0).value = rs1.team
  set rs2 = qry1.execute
  debug pring rs2.fields("Score")
  rs2.close
  rs1.movenext
end do
rs1.close
```